# Silverlight 4: Consuming a webservice in .web

Tags: silverlight, web-services, silverlight-4.0, webclient

Is it possible to call a webservice if you reference it in .Web?

[image]

If yes, how can I access it in MainPage.xaml.cs?

The reason why I am asking this is for easy changing of config in deployment

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to reference the service from your Silverlight project. However, you could expose a new service from your .Web project, expose the methods from your MachineHistoryWS, then add a service reference from that to your Silverlight project.

Comment: Actually, your answer is my current implementation however the reason why I asked this question because of the deployment. Since my client app is packed as xap, I need to uncompress, change the clientconfig to point the web service to a different URL, then compress. I don't want to do the compression and uncompression.